# composer do not make good action

Tags: php, .htaccess, composer-php

I try to install via a web admin a module. The action call a function allowing via composer to install a library.

My problem is composer create everytime an htaccess inside my shop directory with an access denied.

Conclusion, it's impossible the display the website

I do not need this htaccess. 
How to resolve this problem that.

```
/shop/.htaccess ===> do not need this files (create automatically)
/shop/composer.lock
/shop/composer.json
```

```php
public function __construct()
{
  static::$root = CORE::getConfig('dir_root', 'Shop');
  static::$composerJson = static::$root . 'composer.json';

  //define  composer environment
  putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . self::$root);
  putenv('COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=' . CORE::BASE_DIRECTORY . '/Work/Cache/Composer/');
}

public static function install($library = null)
{
  if (self::checkExecute() == true) {
    if (is_null($library)) {
      $result = false;
    } else {
      $cmd = 'cd ' . self::$root . ' && composer require  ' . $library . ' 2>&1';
      exec($cmd, $output, $return); // update dependencies

      $result = $output[2];
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try setting `htaccess-protect` to `false` in your `composer.json`. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#htaccess-protect

Comment: ok but where I insert this setting inside the composer.json (config ? ) or can I make that ?  putenv('HTACCESS-PROTECT=FALSE');

Comment: Looks like there is a `COMPOSER_HTACCESS_PROTECT` environment variable you could use. https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-htaccess-protect